# adding an outer while loop to my c program - beginner 1 to continue 0 to stop

Tags: c

This is my first post on stack overflow, so this is my code so far, i'm just starting computer engineering and am having some trouble.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void ) {
   int num, sum = 0, i, ssq = 0, isq, n;

   printf("Enter an integer: ");
   scanf("%d", &num);

   for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
      sum = sum + (i * i);
   }
   printf("The sum of the squares of integers from 0 to %d is %d\n", num, sum);

   while (i >= 0) {
      printf("Would you like to go again? (1 for yes, 0 for no): ");
      scanf("%d", &i);

      printf("Enter an integer: ");
      scanf("%d", &num);

      for (isq = 1; isq <= n; isq++);
          ssq = ssq + (isq * isq);

      printf("The sum of the squares of integers from 0 to %d is %d\n", num, sum);

      if (i == 0) break;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

This is what I have so far believe it or not it took me 12 hours to do the first part, I've literally been up all night working on this, before the `while` loop and now I'm completely lost. I added the `ssq=0`, `isq`, and `n` ints in to try to help with no avail. At this point I'm just rearranging stuff for hours on end, this is my first post so please don't be too hard on me!

Comment: It is **very** important to learn to indent your code correctly. This will greatly increase its readability and maintainability

Comment: If you observe, you have code duplication. Now think what can be done to remove that.

Comment: this line: ` for (isq = 1; isq <= n; isq++);` is referencing the value in the `n` variable, but that value has not been set, so it contains whatever trash was on the stack at the location of `n`.

Comment: the `while()` loop is exited, at the end, if the user enters 0.  However, the code runs through all the (user was trying to skip) code before checking the value of `i`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This contains a whole host of errors, from typos to code duplication, as @HappyCoder has noted above.

**First of all**, the outer part and the loop part do exactly the same. Think about it for a moment. You first do some task, unconditionally, then ask the user if they want to start over. The task itself doesn't change! Hence, what we can do is this:

```
do the task;
ask the user if they want to quit or go on;
if yes, return to the start.
```

In code, this can be done with an *endless loop* that you break out of if the user wants to stop:

```
while(1) {
    // do user input and calculations here;
    printf("Would you like to go again? (1 for yes, 0 for no): ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    if (i == 0)
        break;
}
```

See, now we only have *one* instance of the calculation code! Now, you can throw away half the variables declared in the beginning, since they are duplicate.

**Now** on to the calculations. You have an uninitialized variable, `ssq`, in the loop. See where code duplication can get you. In the outer part, it is initialized properly. Inside the loop, however, it is not guaranteed to hold any concrete value, most likely it contains garbage.

**Also**, as noted by @JohnHascall, this subtle error introduced most likely by a typo:

```
for (isq = 1; isq <= n; isq++); // <---- the evil semicolon
    ssq = ssq + (isq * isq);
```

The semicolon after the `for` loop makes the loop empty, and the summation only happens once, but not in the loop, as you want it to be.

**Then**, you output (print) `sum` not `ssq` inside the loop, which is obviously not what you want to print. **And**, you use the uninitialized `n` variable from outside the loop as the boundary, instead of the user inputted `num`.

I want to add yet **one more**. Sanely naming the variables is a big deal as it helps you to catch potential errors and keep track of how variables are being used throughout the code, not to mention easier understanding of the code by others. Look: `int i` -> `int choice` better isn't it?

**So we can** rewrite the code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void )
{
    int boundary, choice, isq, ssq;

    while (1) {
        printf("Enter an integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &boundary);

        ssq = 0;
        for (isq = 1; isq <= boundary; isq++) {
            ssq = ssq + (isq * isq);
        }

        printf("The sum of the squares of integers from 0 to %d is %d\n", boundary, ssq);

        printf("Would you like to go again? (1 for yes, 0 for no): ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        if (choice == 0)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nicely explained, but PLEASE don't do loops like that.  Get in the habit of ALWAYS using braces on multi-line loops/if's and you will never run into the typo that started this whole thing:  `for (isq = 1; isq <= n; isq++) {` `ssq = ssq + (isq * isq);` `}`

Comment: @JohnHascall  Alright, correcting, thank you for the hint! Some people say the more lines the worse the code, I'm sticking to that when I cut braces off.

Comment: @JohnHascall why did you edit `main(void)`? I've been under the impression that `int argc, char **argv` is the Only One.

Comment: There are two valid signatures for main -- one with `(int, char **)` and one with `( void )` -- if you don't use the command line args, the second is more appropriate.

Comment: OK, remembered. And what would you say to those who instruct to limit methods to 7 lines? (which means you sort of have to cut on braces sometimes)

Comment: 7 lines?  That's absurd!  See here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/137123/coding-guideline-methods-shouldnt-contain-more-than-7-statements for some scathing critiques...

Comment: Seen that many times in "coding style and guideline" books, as it "improves cohesion inside the method". Whereas I've encountered many examples of where it realistically isn't possible to do. OK been there a minute ago, going back to read well. (OpenCV eg has ~200 line methods)

Comment: thank all of you, i wish i could up mark all of your comments, thank you for your kindness i am very new to programming you helped me a lot! this is more helpful than my whole month in my c programming course!!!! thanks so much! hopefully one day i can help the community like you guys helped me!!!!

Comment: you welcome! PS you can easily upvote all three, if you feel so. upvoting and accepting an answer are different actions. you can upvote any number of answers, but you can only accept one.

Comment: i did!! can't thank you guys enough!!! hopefully the way i worded my question and all was in the guidelines. i'm sure i'll be back sooner than later!

Comment: "this is more helpful than my whole month in my c programming course" sitting down on a problem with a mentor is very helpful indeed. **But**, here's the big but, don't skip on the theory in your course! You're going to need it later, believe.

Comment: What does while (1) *mean (sorry all night coding) we haven't learned about anything in parenthesis yet like that.

Comment: In C, any value other than `0` is considered to be "true". Hence, the `while` loop is going to run forever, since its condition is always going to be "true". The only point where the loop may stop is the `break` statement, which is executed when the user inputs "1" or a greater integer.

Comment: ahhhh, i understand. sadly this is the last assignment we're allowed to use break for some reason. is there a replacement for break in c? sorry i can't move this discussion to chat i don't have enough rep points.

Comment: @treysentio see John Hascall's answer below (which is a refactor of my answer). There he uses the `do {}. while()` loop, which *always* executes once before asking for the condition. That way, you put the condition at the end of the loop, and get your desired behavior.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (isq=1; isq<=n; isq++);  
        ssq = ssq + (isq*isq);
```

The problem here is that 'n' is not initialized and not used in above scanf statement, you need to use 'num' instead of 'n'

```
for (isq=1; isq<=num; isq++)  
        ssq = ssq + (isq*isq);
```

Answer (score 1):

One likely problem is here:

```
      for (isq = 1; isq <= n; isq++);
          ssq = ssq + (isq * isq);
```

You probably want:

```
      for (isq = 1; isq <= n; isq++) {
          ssq = ssq + (isq * isq);
      }
```

Also, you should add:

```
      ssq = 0;
```

above that loop (think about your 2nd trip through the loop).

Comment: Nice catch! I use uncrustify to recover formatting in posts like this one, and it obviously added empty braces in place of the semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

Here is @iksemyonov 's answer refactored to honor the "no more than 7 lines in a method" rule (using a hard and fast arbitrary number like 7 is absurd, but the principle of making function do a specific understandable task is reasonable).

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int getBoundary ( void ) {
    int boundary;

    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &boundary);
    return boundary;
}

static int computeSSQ ( int limit ) {
    int ssq = 0;

    for (; limit > 0; --limit) ssq += (limit*limit);
    return ssq;
}

static int again ( void ) {
    int choice;

    printf("Would you like to go again? (1 for yes, 0 for no): ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    return choice;
}

int main ( void ) {
    do {
        int boundary = getBoundary();
        int ssq = computeSSQ(boundary);
        printf("The sum of the squares of integers from 0 to %d is %d\n",
            boundary, ssq);
   } while (again());
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ty a lot! Appreciate the effort. However, is that answer serious, or, like, "tongue in cheek" - we've solved the OP's problem already, more or less? Also, it reminds me of functional programming for some reason, just a gut feeling you know. Oh and why `static`?

Comment: It's a serious answer, but it's in excess of what I would expect for what seems to be an assignment fairly early in a first programming course.

Comment: The `static` pretty much just comes off my fingertips automatically :)  In 'C' it just means the function is not externally visible, which doesn't amount to a hill of beans in a 1-file program.

Comment: I'd also cut down on locals' declarations (by e.g. chaining functions) and put a couple `const` here and there. But it's probably the hidden functional programmer in me speaking.

Comment: Yup, but I didn't want to jump too far astray from the source material.  Obviously, `again()` and `getBoundary()` could easily be coalesced into `int getIntWithPrompt ( const char * prompt)` but then, I'd have to explain const, and ...

Comment: yea we definitely haven't covered static yet. good learning from you guys though. can use all the c knowledge i can get i'm struggling right now, everyone else has programming experience in my class or have took it and failed it before, i have none.

Comment: IMO, about 90% of programming is thinking about and understanding your problem, and 10% writing the code once you do.

Answer (score 1):

You have made a few mistakes here:

1. You have put a semicolon after the for loop inside the while block which should be removed.
2. Inside the while block you have accepted value for 'num' while you have used 'n' in the for loop (for which value is uninitialized). So you should accept the value of 'n' instead of 'num' or else replace 'n' in the for loop with 'num'.
3. If you want to exit the while loop immediately after user inputs 0 then move the if (i == 0) break; statement to below the scanf ("%d", &i) statement.
4. In the printf() statement next to the for loop, you have used value of 'sum' while you have calculated value for ssq.
5. Also you should write ssq = 0 after the printf() statement to reset its value to 0.

Correct all these and the program will work.

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do was basically a menu driven program... i would suggest , like the above one's are right too... but another way you can do is using `do{
//the task , i.e. the sum
} while(i!=0);`

doing this since do while is an exit controlled loop as you might be knowing... so as in earlier stages u can be free from using `break;` keyword...
also as you are starting an early bird tip i would like to give is that the suggestion of using functions by @John above ....is good but not if you are doing mistakes in a normal `int main()` 15 lines code... since if you go in user defined functions like stated above you might go wrong in passing the arguments or basics of function passing... so go for a normal int main code for now...

**Note** i didnt meant that what @ John said was wrong or something...just gave my view/advice